# ¿Como se quitan elementos de un winforms en C#, de forma dinamica?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Me gustaria saber como quitar elementos de mi windows forms mediante C#, actualemnte estoy haciendo una aplicacion con C# y winforms y en una de las partes de mi aplicacion se encuentra una ventana que tiene a dos winforms embebidos dentro de un winform principal, esto debido a que hay dos botones que me indicaran que winform secundario debe ser llamado.

Imagen de la ventana actual.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los elementos que se pueden apreciar estan dentro de un winforms secundario que se llama dentro del winform principal.

Codigo donde se se mete el winform secundario al principal.

```
    public Resguardo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Resguardo_Compra compra = new Resguardo_Compra();
        compra.TopLevel = false;
        compra.Location = new Point(0,50);
        this.Controls.Add(compra);
        compra.Show();
        notSize();
    }
```

Eso se realizar en el constructor y por ende al iniciar la aplicacion, ya lo hace de esa forma correctamente, pero ahora quiero que al darle clic en venta se cambio mi winform por otro que cree en especifico para el modulo de ventas de la misma forma (metiendo el winform secundario en el principal). Asi que pense en remover el winform secundario de compra y despues poner el winform de venta, pero no funciono.

Codigo de reemplazo:

```
private void btnVenta_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Resguardo_Compra compra = new Resguardo_Compra();
    this.Controls.Remove(compra);
    Resguardo_Venta venta = new Resguardo_Venta();
   venta.TopLevel = false;
    venta.Location = new Point(0, 50);
    this.Controls.Add(venta);
    venta.Show();
}
```

Se supone que las dos lineas de arriba deberian borrar el primer winform y las de abajo mostrar el segundo. Alguien que sepa como realizar esta susticion de formularios.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

inicialmente debería ser:

```
compra.Show();
venta.Hide();
```

y para cambiar

```
compra.Hide();
venta.Show();
```

compra y venta deben ser variables globales, para que los puedas acceder en todos los métodos de la clase.

Comment: gracias, rayos pense que era mas complejo. Aunque eso solo lo oculta no lo elimina pero me funciona para mi aplicacion

Comment: exacto solo ocultas y muestras, sin olvidar limpiar los campos.